# How to sum the next n non-empty cells in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

In one column of my LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet, cells have values in an irregular pattern, meaning that an arbitrary number of empty or non-empty cells might follow a non-empty cell.

How can I sum the next n (e.g., 3) non-empty cells?

I found out that I probably need the `SUM` function over a *dynamic range* involving an `IF` statement and the `COUNTA` function. However, I fail to put it all together. For, example, I can sum all non-empty rows in B with `=SUM(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)))`, but how do I reduce this to the next 3 non-empty entries?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you not use `=sum(B:B)`

Comment: No, since I want to sum a fixed number of non-empty cells, e.g., 3. If I do `SUM(B:B)` it sums up all entries in that column, so 7 values in the example.

Comment: Oh, okay, you were throwing me off with "next 3 non-empty cells". Did you want to sum the first three non empty cells?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing formulation. Starting from the row where the cell with the summation formula is located, I want to sum up the next three non-empty cells. In the example, it indeed corresponds to the first three non-empty cells. However, I formulated the sentence in general terms because I would also like to e.g. copy the formula to A6 and then sum 4, 5, and 6 accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a volatile solution (assuming you don't have more than 10k rows):
[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formula]

The array formula in G2 is

```
=SUM(INDEX(B2:$B$10000,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/ISNUMBER(B2:$B$10000))*(ROW(B2:$B$10000)-(ROW(B2)-1)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&D2)))))
```

(you could possibly reduce volatility by hard-coding the array constant - instead of using `INDIRECT()` - but I'm not very familiar with all of LibreOffice's volatile functions)